# Page Query in wrapPageElement of Gatsby?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

In Gatsby I'm trying to use dynamic query in my wrapPageElement, but apparently it doesn't run at all.
I use the same syntax as in normal page queries:

```js
export const query = graphql `
query PageLayout($locale: String) {
  pages: allMarkdownRemark(sort: {fields: [frontmatter___title], order: DESC}, filter: {frontmatter: {draft: {nin: true}}, fields: {locale: {eq: $locale}, collection: {in: ["pages"]}}}) {
    nodes {
      frontmatter {
        title
      }
      fields {
        slug
      }
    }
  }
}`;
```

Any proposal how to implement?
The idea is that, there is a Nav element, which is part of the main Layout, so it should be able to list my pages.

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to use dynamic query in my `wrapPageElement`.

That will never work. `wrapPageElement` is a shared API between `gatsby-browser.js` and `gatsby-ssr.js` that wraps component across pages, it's not intended to trigger queries, it doesn't make sense because page queries happens in pages (or templates) and that context is missing in the `wrapPageElement`.

> The idea is that, there is a Nav element, which is part of the main
> Layout, so it should be able to list my pages.

You can use a [`useStaticQuery`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/) to display all pages like you are doing in the query above, but you don't need to filter it at all. Static queries don't accept dynamic values, like `$locale` is (hence the name) so any kind of filtering would need to be applied in JavaScript code directly.

It's quite common to use isolated components, something like:

```
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";

export const useNavQuery = () => {
  const { pages } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query PageLayout {
        pages: allMarkdownRemark(
          sort: { fields: [frontmatter___title], order: DESC }
          filter: {
            frontmatter: { draft: { nin: true } }
            collection: { in: ["pages"] }
          }
        ) {
          nodes {
            frontmatter {
              title
            }
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  );
  return pages;
};
```

Then:

```
import React from "react"
import { useNavQuery } from "../hooks/use-site-nav"

export default function Nav() {
  const pages = useNavQuery ()
  return <h1>/* your loop through pages */</h1>
}
```

Comment: That was my bet, but you confirmed. Thank you!